# Why builtin JSON builder runs faster as compared to explicit JSON loader?

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests, timeit

I have a web service which gives me HUGE json response. Here, I'm providing iPython code snippet.

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.post("<API endpoint>", data={"number_of_row" : 10000000})

In [3]: r
Out[3]: <Response [200]>

In [4]: import json

In [5]: %timeit json.loads(r.text)
1 loop, best of 3: 36.5 s per loop

In [6]: %timeit r.json()
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

Whey line #5 takes so much of time as compared to line #6? Ultimately, I want JSON object out of the response data received.

Edit #1: Adding stats with `simplejson` and post reversing the parsing.

```
In [11]: r = requests.post("<API endpoint>", data={"number_of_row": 10000000})

In [12]: res = requests.post("<API endppoint>", data={"number_of_row": 10000000})

In [13]: %timeit r.json()
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit res.json()
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit json.loads(r.text)
1 loop, best of 3: 36.5 s per loop

In [16]: %timeit simplejson.loads(r.text)
1 loop, best of 3: 36.3 s per loop
```

And one thing to note, there is no `caching` implemented anywhere. API endpoints are in my control.

Edit #2:

```
In [18]: %timeit json.loads(r.content.decode(requests.utils.guess_json_utf(r.content)))
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit r.json()
10 loops, best of 3: 63.3 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit json.loads(r.text)
1 loop, best of 3: 36.5 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`requests.models.Response.json()` uses `json.loads` (or `simplejson.loads`) interally. So there should be no difference unless you installed `simplejson`.

I suspect the time difference come from network IO; Once the data fetched, it is cached. So the second one (`r.json`) use the cached data; take less time.

If you reverse the order of calls, you will get reversed result.

**EDIT**

`request.models.Response.text` uses `chardet.detect` to guess encoding of the response, while `requests.models.Response.json()` uses `requests.utils.guess_json_utf` which only consider `utf-8`, `utf-16`, `utf-32` according to JSON RFC 4627 section 3.

```
In [1]: content = 'a' * 1000000000

In [2]: import chardet

In [3]: %timeit chardet.detect(content)['encoding']
1 loops, best of 3: 9.6 s per loop

In [4]: import requests.utils

In [5]: %timeit requests.utils.guess_json_utf(content)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 835 ns per loop
```

Comment: I doubt it is n/w IO. Cause when I'm parsing the response, n/w IO is already finished. It's pure parsing logic. Also, I've edited my question with reversed parsing methods, please check.

Comment: @AashishP, It's weird. BTW, caching I meant in `requests`' side, not server-side.

Comment: @AashishP, Could you timeit `json.loads(r.content.decode(requests.utils.guess_json_utf(r.content)))` ?  `Response.text` tries to detect encoding using `chardet` which consider all possible encoding, while `Response.json` uses the `guess_json_utf` which only consider utf-8, utf-16, utf-32.

Comment: @AashishP, In other word, `requests.utils.guess_json_utf(..)` vs `chardet.detect(..)['encoding']`

Comment: Please check Edit #2. You are correct. So, next question is, if I have some non utf characters in the data, I can't go for `r.json()`?